# About what TeX does after it finds commented conditionals with ltxdoc

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, doc

When I thought I understood the concept of the `doc` package, LaTeX proved me wrong.

I was trying to make a file to use with `ltxdoc` when I realised I could not use conditionals in the preamble because they would break things by making TeX read stuff in the preamble from that point on, as it *shouldn't*. Then I tried to MWE-ify that code and stumbled upon a bigger problem.

When I thought I understood the concept of conditionals and expansion, TeX proved me wrong `:)`

Consider the following code (lines numbered to make reading easier):

```
01 % \tracingall
02 % \iffalse meta-comment    ^^A This /iffalse
03 \documentclass{ltxdoc}
04 \def\showfi{\immediate\write0{{/fi\ on line \the\inputlineno}}}%
05 \title{Doc Test}%
06 \newif\ifitsme\itsmetrue
07 \ifitsme\author{Me :)}%
08 \else   \author{Not me :/}%
09 \fi\showfi
10 \begin{document}%
11   \DocInput{\jobname}%
12   \tracingnone
13 \end{document}%
14 % \fi\showfi               ^^A should match this /fi
15 % \fi\showfi               ^^A but it's matching this one
16 % \tracingnone
17 % \maketitle
18 % \endinput
```

When LaTeX starts, comments are comments, so everything goes normally: load `ltxdoc`; define the `\showfi` (to log on what line the `\fi` appears); give it a title to avoid an error; define a new `\ifitsme`, set it to true, which makes `Me :)` the author. Then I call `\showif` just in case (not important now).

So far so good...

Then I `\DocInput` this same file. Not comments aren't comments anymore and things go off the rails `:)`

`\DocInput` starts reading the file from start. I turn on full-logging with `\tracingall` and then comes the usual `\iffalse meta-comment` from `.dtx` files. This `\iffalse` usually goes up to the `\fi` right after the `\end{document}` to continue reading the source.

#### What I think it *should* do:

This won't be the case because when TeX finds a false conditional it skips code *without* expansion until the next `\else` or `\fi`, which here is the `\else` in line `08` (because TeX doesn't expand `\ifitsme` to find out it's an `\iftrue`). I would expect TeX to read that `\else` and execute `\author{Not me :/}`, then read the `\fi` from line `09` and show `{/fi\ on line 9}` in the log (Then another `\begin{document}` would come up and break things, but this is an error for another day).

#### What it *does*:

TeX doesn't skip to the `\fi` on line `09`, neither to the one on line `14`, but to an *extra* `\fi` (that I added because it would throw an error otherwise) on line `15`. The log shows:

```
{\iffalse: (level 1) entered on line 2}
{false}
{\fi: \iffalse (level 1) entered on line 2}

\showfi ->\immediate \write 0{{/fi\ on line \the \inputlineno }}
{\immediate}
\write->{/fi\ on line \the \inputlineno }
{/fi\ on line 15}
```

#### What:

What is TeX *actually* doing that it does not behave as I expected? Why does it skip not only the `08 \else... 09 \if`, but also the `14 \fi`, requiring an additional `\fi` inserted there for no (apparent) good reason?

---

Code without line-numbers for copy-pasting:

```
% \tracingall
% \iffalse meta-comment    ^^A This /iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\def\showfi{\immediate\write0{{/fi\ on line \the\inputlineno}}}%
\title{Doc Test}%
\newif\ifitsme\itsmetrue
\ifitsme\author{Me :)}%
\else   \author{Not me :/}%
\fi\showfi
\begin{document}%
  \DocInput{\jobname}%
  \tracingnone
\end{document}%
% \fi\showfi               ^^A should match this /fi
% \fi\showfi               ^^A but it's matching this one
% \tracingnone
% \maketitle
% \endinput
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you correctly say, when you do `pdflatex test.dtx`, the file is read with `%` a comment character. When TeX finds `\DocInput`, it will basically ignore `%` at the start of lines and make `^^A` a comment character. So your input is essentially

```
% \iffalse meta-comment    ^^A This /iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\def\showfi{\immediate\write0{{/fi\ on line \the\inputlineno}}}%
\title{Doc Test}%
\newif\ifitsme\itsmetrue
\ifitsme\author{Me :)}%
\else   \author{Not me :/}%
\fi\showfi
\begin{document}%
\iffalse meta-comment    ^^A This /iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\def\showfi{\immediate\write0{{/fi\ on line \the\inputlineno}}}%
\title{Doc Test}%
\newif\ifitsme\itsmetrue
\ifitsme\author{Me :)}%
\else   \author{Not me :/}%
\fi\showfi
\begin{document}%
  \DocInput{\jobname}%
\end{document}%
\fi\showfi               ^^A should match this /fi
\fi\showfi               ^^A but it's matching this one
\maketitle
\endinput
\end{document}%
% \fi\showfi               ^^A should match this /fi
% \fi\showfi               ^^A but it's matching this one
% \maketitle
% \endinput
```

Now `\iffalse` is seen, but `\ifitsme` *is* a conditional found twice in skipped text, so two matching `\fi` are looked for. And this is where things go wrong, because there is no more a matching `\fi` for `\iffalse`, unless you add one, like you do.

The `\fi` in the uncommented line with “should match this /fi” matches `\ifitsme` after `\newif`.

Defining conditionals inside conditionals is always open to this kind of problems. Use

```
\expandafter\newif\csname ifitsme\endcsname
```

so when the code is inside skipped text there will be no conditional at all.

Comment: Thanks, I almost got it. I just don't understand one thing: You say `The \fi in the uncommented line with “should match this /fi” matches \ifitsme`. But `\ifitsme` is not a *proper* conditional, but an alias for an `\iftrue`, right? So it would require TeX to expand `\ifitsme` to find out it's a conditional, therefore search for a matching `\fi`. In my understanding TeX doesn't know that `\ifitsme` is a conditional, so it should use the `\fi` on line 9 to match the `\iffalse`, ignoring the `\ifitsme` as any other control sequence. What is wrong with this statement?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik naturally TeX must know after \newif that \ifitsme is a conditional. conditionals would not be usable (nestable) it this weren't the case.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No, TeX knows `\ifitsme` is either `\iftrue` or `\iffalse`, because `\itsmetrue` does `\let\ifitsme\iftrue` and similarly for the false setting. It's a feature of the language. If you say `\let\repeat\fi` (which is actually done in the LaTeX kernel), then you can use `\repeat` wherever `\fi` is expected.

Comment: Oooohhh, I got it, the assignment is done with `\let`, so it doesn't require expansion, then TeX searches for the `\fi`. Indeed Ulrike, if this weren't the case, conditionals would be useless. Thanks a lot, to all of you :)

Answer (score 12):

Your `\newif` command is inside a `\iffalse` so it is not seen, and `\ifitsme` is now either not an "if" at all, or if the `\newif` has been executed earlier, the `\ifitsme` behind the `\newif` counts too and you have one "if" too much:

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newif\ifitsme
\iffalse

\ifitsme hello \fi

\fi 
\end{document}
```

This fails

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\iffalse
\newif\ifitsme
\ifitsme hello \fi

\fi 
\end{document}
```

This fails too

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newif\ifitsme

\iffalse
\newif\ifitsme %\newif not seen, but \ifitsme so one fi missing
\ifitsme hello \fi

\fi 
\end{document}
```

Morale: Better don't use `\newif` inside `\if`--`\fi`.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, but I don't follow :/ I understand what happens in your example (maybe because it's much simpler :), the `\iffalse` is closed by the `hello \fi` and the other `\fi` throws an `Extra \fi` error. But in my example, the `\newif` *is* seen because in the "% is comment" pass, the `\iffalse` on line 1 is not seen and (I presume) everything goes as it should. But then in the "% is ignored" pass, the `\iffalse` on line 1 should match with the `\else` on line 8 and the `\fi` on line 9. But it doesn't, instead it goes two *more* `\fi`s ahead...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I see what you mean. I added an edit for the docinput case.

Comment: After egreg's answer I (finally) understood your third example. I need lots of words to understand things :P. Thanks a lot Ulrike :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a technique for more safely skipping stuff. Put it between

```
\bgroup\catcode2 0 \catcode`\\ 12 ^^Biffalse
```

and

```
^^Bfi^^Begroup
```

What this does is to inhibit `\` starting control sequences. So you are sure that whatever you do with `\if`, `\fi`, `\else`,  or `\if...` etc.. in-between this will have nil influenc.

And it assigns to ascii byte `0x02` this meaning of starting control sequences. we can do a safe `^^Biffalse/^^Bfi` thing.

I am not using `^^A` as doc assigns to it a use as comment character and we want to keep that (especially if the editor highlights appropriately).

I guess with your MWE it would look like this

```
% \tracingall
% \bgroup\catcode2 0 \catcode`\\ 12 ^^Biffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\def\showfi{\immediate\write0{{/fi\ on line \the\inputlineno}}}%
\title{Doc Test}%
\newif\ifitsme\itsmetrue
\ifitsme\author{Me :)}%
\else   \author{Not me :/}%
\fi\showfi
\begin{document}%
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}%
  \tracingnone
\end{document}%
% \fi\showfi
% ^^Bfi^^Begroup
% \tracingnone
% \maketitle
% \endinput
```

with the file being saved as `test.dtx`.

Caveat: although I use doc for my `dtx` I never use `\DocInput` (because it led into endless problems with the way I wanted to handle guards, and because I don't want the documentation part (not the one of code implementation, but the user manual) to be "commented-out") so I don't know if that would be your use case.

Comment: Thanks, this looks safer indeed :) Could you name one package of yours that doesn't use `\DocInput` as you mentioned? I'm interested in options. I use `\DocIput` basically because it's the way everyone does, so there are plenty examples to learn from...

Comment: Most of my packages have a rather complicated `dtx` structure because it is most of the time self-extracting or with various things such as README.md, or Makefile. Notice that if you want to refer in a README or a CHANGE LOG to a TeX conditional `\iffoo` your are not going to be able to do it with `\csname...`. One with a relatively simple `dtx` is [`bnumexpr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bnumexpr) but it does use `\iffalse/\fi`. [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) uses the technique as explained here (it starts at line 67 in `etoc.dtx` and skipping ends at line 409).